# eval "$(rbenv init -)" does not work when referenced from ~/.zshrc (OS X)

Tags: ruby, zsh, rbenv

This is one those strange things, although I'm sure the most recent installation of Sierra has something to do with this.
In fact, yesterday night I had to completely (manually remove) the whole rbenv folder to make it working again.

In a nutshell, the following `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` has been added immediately after the PATH declaration in the ~/.zshrc file. 
However, when launching the iTerm console, that line pass ignored and in fact all the gems under the shims are ignored. This should also result in the default ruby version to be loaded, which is not the case as a `ruby -v` returns my global 2.3.1 recently installed.

The funny thing is that a `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` at a command line properly resolve and all works fine after that.

I have another Mac, where I can't install Sierra and the same settings, same ZSH version etc. works just fine.

Does anybody experience the same?

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: do you have `rbenv` in your PATH? try `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"` and then
`eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in your `~/.zshrc`

Comment: I am on Sierra, have everything working. Also you should have xcode installed? Do you have it?

Comment: the path above is not in place, but when I rub rbenv from the same terminal windows that gets executed, so this doesn't sound to be the problem? A which rbenv returns the following path /local/bin/rbenv

Comment: yes, I removed this line with PATH and it seems like it still works...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've raked the net for 30 minutes without results, so I did a simple test. 
Instead of copy and pasting the results proposed by the `rbenv init`, I typed what is proposed into the ~/.zshrc file to get it working like a charm.

I can only assume that some characters shown on screen are encoded in some different way, hence they generate the problem.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question so much as make it moot. I'd just delete it.

Comment: Well, not sure why you believe it does not answer. It does IMHO as a copy and paste from what it is proposed doesn't seem to work.